# How callbacks are written in squelize nodejs?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

How can we have callbacks like before_save or after_find before calling save or find function in sequelize nodejs ?

Answer (score 0):

The features was added 5 days ago in https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/pull/894, so there is no official documentation. However, the PR itself is very well documented, so you should be able to figure it out from there. Please note that the code in the PR is not in NPM yet, so you'll have to reference master directly in your package file to get access to the feature

Answer (score 0):

**there are 4 ways you can go about it .**

1) use a bluebird promise to handle the promise of multiple sequelize calls with promisify.all with a .then()

2) use a .then() for individual call for example:

```
 Model.findAll({attributes: ['foo', ['bar', 'baz']]}).then(res=>{Do whatever })
```

3) Use async await to handle the promise

```
const test = async () =>{
  let value = await Model.findAll({attributes: ['foo', ['bar', 'baz']]})

 // Do whatever 
}
```

4) use combine then and async await

```
 const test = async () =>{
      let value = await Model.findAll({attributes: ['foo', ['bar', 'baz']]}).then(res=>res.filter(id=>id===2))

     //here in .then the filter operation is done which is awaited to maintain synchronization whose value is finally returned to value variable that can be used further in the code   
     // Do whatever 
}
```